# How to make `:active::after` work like `:hover::after`?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, styled-components, react-typescript

When I use `&:hover::after` on my custom button component (using styled-components btw) everything works fine. But when I switch to `&:active::after`, to make the animation happen when the button is clicked, nothing works. Any ideas?

```
    /* Content under the drip */
    content: 'DEPOSIT'; 
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: white; /* Color of text */
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }

  &:hover::after {
    /* The drip overlay */
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -50%;
    left: -25%;
    height: 550%;
    width: 150%;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, hsl(321, 98%, 60%), hsl(321, 98%, 75%)); /* Color of moving object */
    border-radius: 40%;
      animation: ${spin} 6s ease-out forwards;
    }
  }`;
```

Comment: How, exactly, are you testing this? Do you realise that `:active` applies only **‘while the mouse button is held down** and the state ends when the button is released?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that! I thought it was like an onClick. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` state should work the same way as `:hover`, but is very volatile and therefore hard to grab. You could use your browser dev tools to enforce element states so taht you can it inspect it. The screenshot shows the Chrome Devtools, but this feature is available in all major browsers.

I hope this helps to find out, if the `:active` state really isn't showing up.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools]

Comment: Yeah I see how it can be very volatile with my new found knowledge from Quentin. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to make an `onClick` prop that switches between the two styles, with a bool switch for instance, creating the illusion that it's all a single button with 2 animations.